# Parse numeric ifconfig flags

Tags: unix, networking, ifconfig

The ifconfig command outputs its [flags](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5166/6mbb1kq2q?l=en&a=view#INTERFACE%20FLAGS) in both textual and numeric format. While I can find a reference [here or there](http://books.google.com/books?id=t7pHu7sIUkQC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=ifconfig+numeric+flags&source=bl&ots=5tG7fK7qzf&sig=A5Z4Gem5mmDeeFsiue4LIeFpVgk&hl=en&ei=7POTSuPxDo2KswPZ69TPDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=ifconfig%20numeric%20flags&f=false) to the numeric flags, I cannot find any indication on how to interpret (mask) the number.

```
qfe2: flags=1100843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,ROUTER,IPv4> mtu
  1500 index 4
  usesrc vni0
  inet 1.2.3.4 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 1.2.3.255
  ether 0:3:ba:17:4b:e1
vni0: flags=20011100c1<UP,RUNNING,NOARP,NOXMIT,ROUTER,IPv4,VIRTUAL>
  mtu 0 index 5
  srcof qfe2
  inet 3.4.5.6 netmask ffffffff
```

In the above output, note the following:

```
flags=1100843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,ROUTER,IPv4>
```

The numeric value "`1100843`" maps to the flags "`UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,ROUTER,IPv4`".

Is there a reference somewhere that I'm simply not seeing that describes how to mask each flag (`UP,BROADCAST,`etc.) out of the encoded "`flags=NNNNNNNN`" value?

**EDIT**: Clarification of exactly which flag I'm interested in masking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag values are defined in the header file [`/usr/include/net/if.h`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/net/if.h#l101) (on Solaris).  The value shown is the bitwise-OR of the flags that are set for that interface.

Comment: Good find! And I happen to be on Solaris, so hopefully those values are trustworthy.