# Solaris: Programmatic interface to ifconfig?

Tags: network-programming, solaris, ifconfig

I'm looking for a programmatic interface to the Solaris [ifconfig(1M)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/ifconfig-1m.html#scrolltoc) command.

Apparently Linux has the [getifaddrs(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) command, but as far as I can tell this has [not been ported to Solaris](http://markmail.org/message/t74kvl63savhzrzp).

Short of attempting to use the code at the [link above](http://markmail.org/message/t74kvl63savhzrzp), is there any way to determine [ifconfig(1M)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/ifconfig-1m.html#scrolltoc)-type data (network interface presence, state, etc.) without forking the system command and [parsing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328678/parse-numeric-ifconfig-flags)?

Answer (score 2):

getifaddrs() was recently integrated into the source code for future OpenSolaris & Solaris releases, but that doesn't help your code run on current releases:

- [6731945 need BSD getifaddrs() API](http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6731945)
- [OpenSolaris source: usr/src/lib/libsocket/inet/getifaddrs.c](https://java.net/projects/solaris/sources/on-src/content/usr/src/lib/libsocket/inet/getifaddrs.c)

Until then you'll need to use the `SIOCGLIFCONF` ioctls, which you should find lots of examples of in open source code, including the link you posted.

Comment: `getifaddrs()` is now available in Solaris 11 and later (which was in the future when I wrote the above in 2010, but was released in 2011).

Answer (score 2):

I have an implementation here, IPv4-only based on `SIOCGIFCONF` `ioctl()`'s and IP family agnostic version using `SIOCGLIFCONF`:

http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/getifaddrs.c

Tested on SPARC/Solaris 10 and x86/OpenSolaris 2008.11 & 2009.06, LGPL 2.1 license.

Answer (score 0):

Real men use `ioctl` ;)

Take a look at [if(7P)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1475/if-7p.html#scrolltoc).