# How to get list of network interface device specific files in Solaris

Tags: network-programming, solaris, ioctl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solaris: Programmatic interface to ifconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655544/solaris-programmatic-interface-to-ifconfig)

How do I get the list of all "/dev/net0 /dev/bge0, Network Interface device file", using C program.

Comment: Not really. Both are different by all means. May be I will get something better than this to get all the files listed.

Comment: If you're looking for network interfaces, the only sensible way is to actually ask the operating system -- if you THEN want the files, from the interface info you can CONSTRUCT the filename. Otherwise you'll never know if your list is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly, you need all presented network devices files in /dev? Then just run

```
ls /dev/net* /dev/bge*
```

and parse results.

Comment: The OP asked for a c program

Comment: I wish it would have been like that, but unfortunately I need to get it using C program. Can't use parsing mechanism.

Comment: yes, I understand. But is is enough for you to ls all devices and get results?

Comment: What about also looking for `hme*`? Or `nge*`? There's no way of knowing the complete list by guessing.