# Is there any getifaddrs() alternative on HP-UX, Solaris or AIX?

Tags: c++, c, solaris, aix, hp-ux

I'm trying to implement a application that uses the `getifaddrs()` function from `<ifaddrs.h>` across multiple platforms. My goal is to retrieve network interface related info (IP, IPv6, Netmask, Broadcast, Scope, and HWAddress).

I have successfully implemented it on Linux, but it seems that the `ifaddrs.h` header isn't present on the above platforms (HP-UX, AIX, Solaris).

What is the recommended approach for these platforms?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139811/1187415, which should work on Solaris and AIX as well, and can be extended for IPv6 (I think).

Comment: @MartinR: After having commented out the netmask query. it compiles and runs on `HP-UX B.11.23 U ia64` listing the interface's IP addresses (no IPv6 here so not tested).

Comment: For AIX, I would go find an open BSD implementation of netstat or ifconfig.  The concepts of the code should be the same as what AIX has.  The old Steve's books would help you out too.  I would not be surprised if getifaddrs does not do something similar if it is implemented as a library routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solaris 11 and later have [`getifaddrs()` already in libsocket](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29035/getifaddrs-3socket.html).  For older Solaris releases, see the answer to [Solaris: Programmatic interface to ifconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655544/solaris-programmatic-interface-to-ifconfig) here on StackOverflow.

Comment: is there any lib for HP-UX that contains getifaddrs()?